# PHP: moving the checked elements(via checkbox) from one array to another

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
<form action = 'xx.php' method = 'POST'>

<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['personA']))
{
    $personA = array('Jack', 'Dave', 'Smith', 'Daniel', 'Peter');
    $personB = array('Tom');
}

else
{
    $personA = $_SESSION['personA'];
    $personB = $_SESSION['personB'];
}


if($_POST['submit1'])
{
$chk1 = $_POST["check1"];


foreach($chk1 as $ch)
{
    echo $ch;
}
}

echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

if($_POST['submit2'])
{
$chk2 = $_POST["check2"];


foreach($chk2 as $ch)
{
    echo $ch;
}
}

echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';
?>

<html>
<body>
<form>

Table personA:
<fieldset style= "width: 200px;">
<?php
foreach($personA as $a)
echo '<input type = "checkbox" name = "check1[]">'.$a.'<br />';

echo '</fieldset>';
echo '<br />';
echo '<input type = "submit" name = "submit1">';
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';
?>

Table personB:
<fieldset style= "width: 200px;">

<?php
foreach($personB as $a)
echo '<input type = "checkbox" name = "check2[]">'.$a.'<br />';

echo '</fieldset>';
echo '<br />';
echo '<input type = "submit" name = "submit2">';

echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';
print_r ($personA);
echo '<br />';
print_r ($personB);
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's how I want it to work:

-I select(for example) Jack, Dave and Smith via checking checkboxes at their names and press the submit button. They get moved from array PersonA into array PersonB

-I select(for example) Tom via checking checkbox at his name and press the submit button. He gets moved from array personB into array personB

So now the arrays should look like this:
$personA = array('Daniel', 'Peter','Tom');
$personB = array('Jack', 'Dave', 'Smith');

-The program allows me to keep doing this, until I press either of the submit buttons with none of the checkboxes checked. It should then display everyone from both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to make sure that they are initialized. After that you need to track all values, since the natural behavior is stateless, you need to use sessions, and from there you need to fetch the values of checkboxes inside those sessions. Consider this example: (I just used `index.php` as an example)

```
<?php
session_start();
// initialize default values
$personA = array('Jack', 'Dave', 'Smith', 'Daniel', 'Peter');
$personB = array('Tom');

// initializations
if(!isset($_SESSION['personA'])) {
    $_SESSION['personA'] = $personA; 
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['personB'])) {
    $_SESSION['personB'] = $personB; 
}

// handle transfer a => b
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $check1 = $_POST['check1'];
    foreach($check1 as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION['personB'][] = $value;
        $key = array_search($value, $_SESSION['personA']);
        unset($_SESSION['personA'][$key]);
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
}

// handle transfer b => a
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    $check2 = $_POST['check2'];
    foreach($check2 as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION['personA'][] = $value;
        $key = array_search($value, $_SESSION['personB']);
        unset($_SESSION['personB'][$key]);
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
}

// simple reset
if(isset($_POST['reset'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['personA']);
    unset($_SESSION['personB']);
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>

<!-- 
The important part here is that, you loop the values of those sessions, not the POST values, because sessions are the ones that are saved.
-->
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <fieldset style="border: 1px solid gray; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <?php foreach($_SESSION['personA'] as $key => $value): ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /> <?php echo $value; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Transfer to B" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset style="border: 1px solid gray; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <?php foreach($_SESSION['personB'] as $key => $value): ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check2[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /> <?php echo $value; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Transfer to A" />
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: @user2987364 Your welcome, an upvote/accept answer is appreciated. good day